# ASP.NET Core route attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, attributerouting

My controller code looks like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PaymentDetailController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetPaymentDetail()
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

I am trying to access like this

```
http://localhost:47744/api/paymentdetail
http://localhost:47744/api/paymentdetail/GetPaymentDetail
```

I cant access my controller and method

Comment: `paymentdetail` is the name of the **controller** - `GetPaymentDetail` is the action method - which gets combined to a complete URL of `/api/paymentdetail/GetPaymentDetail` - as desired - so what's the issue or question, really???

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use route like this

```
http://localhost:47744/api/paymentdetail/GetPaymentDetail
```

you need this controller route

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class PaymentDetailController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetPaymentDetail()
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

if you want to use route like this

```
http://localhost:47744/api/GetPaymentDetail
```

you need this controller route

```
[Route("api/[action]")]
public class PaymentDetailController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetPaymentDetail()
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

or you can use both routes

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PaymentDetailController : ControllerBase
{      
     [Route("~/api/PaymentDetail/GetPaymentDetail")]  
     [Route("~/api/GetPaymentDetail")]
    public async Task<string> GetPaymentDetail()
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PaymentDetailController : ControllerBase
{   
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetPaymentDetail")]
    public async Task<string> GetPaymentDetail()
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

Like this?

Comment: Since the method name is already `GetPaymentDetail`, I don't see how this would help in any way.... the URL will be exactly the same ...

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but this line of code doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It can be accessed using http://localhost:47744/api/paymentdetail, and the route will look for the action of the first get method.
[image]

Or like this：

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PaymentDetailController : ControllerBase
    { 

      [HttpGet("GetPaymentDetail")]

        public async Task<string> GetPaymentDetail()
        {
            return "Success";
        }
```

Comment: please can you share startup.cs class code

Answer (score 0):

Your URL points to `/api/paymentdetail` but your ActionMethod is called `GetPaymentDetail()`.

The Url that should be working would most likely be `/api/paymentdetail/getpaymentdetail`.

You might want to rename your ActionMethod to `Get()` since it is already clear what resource you are getting.

Comment: `paymentdetail` is the name of the **controller** - `GetPaymentDetail` is the action method - which gets combined to a complete URL of `/api/paymentdetail/GetPaymentDetail` - as desired ..

Comment: Overlooked the second URL in the original post. You are right. The second URL should be working.